# How remove a item from a list with jinja2

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

Ansible: 2.4.9

I like to execute a task on to server list from my "groups" magic var without "server_summer03".

Code:

```
host: all
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    vars:
      ansible_host: "{{ item | reject('search', 'server_summer03') }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ groups['summer'] }}"
```

But the output is:

```
msg: '<generator object _select or _reject at 0x7f013ca....
```

Comment: That `<generator` business is because `map` and its peers are lazy, doing only work when requested, and thus they need a terminating `| list` to "collapse" the generator chain into a concrete final list of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use when:

```
host: all
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    vars:
      ansible_host: "{{ item }}
    when: item != 'server_summer03'
    with_items:
      - "{{ groups['summer'] }}"
```